# Importing ESRI shp / gdb files with M value into Postgis

Tags: qgis, postgis, gdal, file-geodatabase

Has anyone done this successfully? I have been using DB Manager in QGIS 2.12 and my MutilinestringM values are converted to Multilinestring in PostGIS. When I use the PostGIS shapefile importer, this does not happen and the lines are converted successfully.

I thought based on reading [this](http://www.gdal.org/drv_shapefile.html) that perhaps better support for M values was coming in GDAL 2.0. However, I have tested with a nightly release of QGIS using this version and that doesn't seem to be the case.

There are a number of different components to this so it's difficult to know which particular element is at fault here, the plugin, QGIS in general, GDAL or even PostGIS.

Comment: Better support for M values will come with GDAL 2.1 https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc61_support_for_measured_geometries.

Comment: The trac page announces that this is closed https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6063 but the ticket is not in 2.1 milestones and the github link on the RFC page doesn't work. So is development being done outside of the trunk?

Comment: Development is done into trunk. See the timeline and search for XYZM geometries and the RFC https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/timeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have imported many xyzm shapefiles into Postgis with the Postgis Shapefiles Import/Export Manager in pgAdminIII.

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have said I had done this. You're right this does work, but my question was more about it working in QGIS thus avoiding the need to transfer other formats to a SHP.